# Match two taxonomies to display a specific content

Tags: categories, taxonomy, query, tax-query

I have a page divided in two bars.

- The left bar is a side menu, which shows contents for a specific country (ie: if I am in the Mexico page, there are options listing Cancun, Acapulco, Mexico City... if I am in Italy page, there are options listing Rome, Milan, Florence and so on);
- The right bar is the full content, that display the pack information of the destination, so if I am in the Italy page and click on Rome, the user will see in this right bar all the information regarding prices, flights, sightseeing and so on;

I have to match these two bars each other. When I am checking the content of the destination in the right bar, the left bar should match the correct menu country.

The way I analyzed it was applying taxonomies for the menu and for the pack information. So, when I am making a page for Rome, I apply the "Italy" taxonomy, or if I am making a page for Cancun, I apply the "Mexico" taxonomy and so on for many other destinations I have.

That is the way I am querying the left bar/side menu (content-sidemenu.php)

```
<?php
  $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'side_menu',
      'posts_per_page'=> 1,
      'tax_query'     => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'countries',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => array( **??????** )
          )
        )
  );
  $the_menu = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_menu->have_posts() ) : $the_menu->the_post(); ?>
?>
```

The right bar is slightly similar (just the `post_type` has different values depending on the page), but the `tax_query` is the same. So, how could I make them match??

Thank you!

Comment: it's not really clear what your structure is. you mention multiple *taxonomies*, but not what those taxonomies are. perhaps you mean multiple *terms* within a single *taxonomy*?

Comment: Yeah, I have 32 countries registered in a taxonomy called "countries". My site structure contains two bars (left and right, as I mentioned). If the right side shows content about "Italy", so the left side should display the menu for Italy. In my CPT called "side_menu" I check the taxonomy for Italy. And for my CPT called "pack" I check the taxonomy for Italy. So I need to match the "side_menu" terms (italy, mexico, brazil, usa, canada...) with the "pack" terms when both are displayed in the bars!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

```
<?php
  // You need to define the post id from the post you are outputting in the right bar so that the left bar knows how to match up the terms
  $country = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'countries' )

  $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'side_menu',
      'posts_per_page'=> 1,
      'tax_query'     => array(
        // 'relation'    => 'AND', /* I don't think you need this unless it has another purpose */
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'countries',
          // This only works since you are selecting just one term per post
          // Works by retrieving the first and only term id from the post in the right bar
          'terms'    => array_shift(array_keys($country))
          )
        )
  );
  $the_menu = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_menu->have_posts() ) : $the_menu->the_post(); ?>
?>
```